# UIAlertView button is disabled even after picking date from UIDatePicker in iOS 7

Tags: uialertview, uidatepicker, ios7.1

The problem is that after picking date from UIDatePicker the "Ok" button of UIAlertView is disabled.I tried ,but no luck.

```
-(BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView
```

should be called whenever we type anything in textfield,but when date is entered it's not getting called,but if i type anything from keyboard,its ok then.[image]

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 1)
       {
        alertView1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Done",nil];
        alertView1.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput;
        alertView1.tag=1;
        alertText = [alertView1 textFieldAtIndex:0];
        itemText = [alertView1 textFieldAtIndex:1];
                alertText.inputView=datePicker;
        itemText.inputView=secondPicker;
        [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(firstTF) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [secondPicker addTarget:self action:@selector(secondTF) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [alertText setPlaceholder:@"From Date"];
        [itemText setPlaceholder:@"To Date"];
        itemText.secureTextEntry = NO;
        [alertView1 show];
}

- (void)firstTF
{
    NSDate *date = datePicker.date;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    alertText.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
}

- (void)secondTF
 {
    NSDate *date = secondPicker.date;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    itemText.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
 }


- (BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView
 {
    NSString *inputText = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];

    if( [inputText length] > 0)
    {
         NSLog(@"alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton: was called!");
         return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: How u calling this.-(BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView..also check ur textfiels delgate as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are not calling it to validate again..After values get inserted you should write this line to call validation..

```
[alertText sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

in this method of yours..

```
- (void)firstTF
```